# Execute another script inside heredoc Doc That expect user input in shell

Tags: bash, shell, sh, ksh

I have a script where based upon user input i need to call another script that is run by pbrun as admin so i made a menu with the `PS3` and `select` and based upon the input i call a function inside which i'm running a pbrun and pass a here doc as input like this.

```
function callS {
pbrun -l /bin/su - admin <<'INNER_EOF'
/home/ankur/testWithout.ksh
INNER_EOF
}
```

Now every thing runs fine but if i call a script that also uses `PS3` and `select` to give menu and needs user input from command line to proceed i'm not able to provide the calling script any input as the provided input is taken by my script not the one i call as admin

Any idea how can i achieve this.?

PS: I cannot use `expect` as also cannot install it. Does not have access to install on systems.

ADMIN Script is written using `KSH` shell

Comment: What i meant was the admin script is written in KSH.. Will EDIT

Comment: @andlrc A bit of Explanation Will be more useful about why this work ?

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that you want to *pipe* the output:

```
/home/ankur/testWithout.ksh | pbrun -l /bin/su - admin
```

Or use [process substitution](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessSubstitution):

```
pbrun -l /bin/su - admin < <(/home/ankur/testWithout.ksh)
```

`command <(...)` is a *process substitution*, which creates a temporary "file" in `/proc/self/fd/` for `...` to write to, and that temporary file's *name* is returned as an argument for `command`:

```
% echo <(ls)
/proc/self/fd/11
```

---

*Here docs* are for text, and with `<< 'xyz'` the input is interpreted as a single quoted string, so *command substitution* wouldn't work, and neither would *parameter expansion*.

`command < file` will redirect `file` as input for `command`.

Comment: No I'm not trying to pipe the output. The called second script should also run in interactive prompt. but when running through pbrun it's not running in the interactive shell